# Cannot change space while agent is moving

Tags: anylogic

I'm totally new to Anylogic (only learned it in 3 days). I have an agent which is moving between 2 nodes of a network. When the Fleet reaches the node, it needs to perform something (flowchart). In the flowchart, there is service where the agent location in the queue follows a path. Then I got the error below.

```
Exception during discrete event execution:
root.Fleet[0]:
Cannot change the space while agent is moving. Please call stop() method.
java.lang.RuntimeException: root.Fleet[0]:
Cannot change the space while agent is moving. Please call stop() method.
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.AgentExtensionImpl.error(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.gb.setSpace(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.ExtAgentWithSpatialMetricsDelegate.setSpace(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.setSpace(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.x.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Wait.e(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Wait$8.onEnter(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.receiveImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal$a.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.LibraryEventHandler$a.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.h(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.nj(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$a.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried agent.setEnvironment(node.getEnvironment()) but it's not working. Can someone tell me what I did wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your agents are still moving while they arrive at the `Service` element. You should make sure they arrive first before changing their location in the service queue.